# Which layer should be responsible for Notification management in Android MVP?

Tags: android, android-notifications, mvp, android-mvp

I'm sure that it shouldn't be handled by any `View` or `Presenter` coupled with `Activity` because they are not present when app is running in the background.

Is it a good idea to treat notifications as another `View` with a singleton `Presenter`?

Comment: By notification, do you mean restarting a given activity using pending intent?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No. Click on notification can fire some Activity but main intent is to indicate background processes in my application and take user advice when interaction required

Comment: What did you end up using in the end?

Comment: @adrcotfas, If I remember correctly, it was `FeatureNotificationManager`, a wrapper around native `NotificationManager`.  
It had methods such as `showNotification()`, `hideNotification()`, `isNotificationVisible()`, etc.  
The best conclusion that came into my head was that notification management is a responsibillity of `FeatureInteractor`,  
so `FeatureNotificationManager` became its private property.  
`FeatureNotificator` also can be a good name for it.